# How to properly handle exception in symfony API request

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I have the following code for an API call.

```
try {
    $response = $this->guzzleClient->request(
        Request::METHOD_POST,
        $url,
        [
            'json' => $payload,
        ]
    );
} catch (BadResponseException $e) {

    throw $e->getResponse();
}
```

But I am receiving following error for some wrong input.

> (1/1) FatalThrowableError Cannot throw objects that do not implement
>   Throwable

If I write `NotFoundHttpException` instead of `BadResponseException` it works. But that is not the solution.

Comment: `$e->getResponse()` is a `string`. And you cannot throw `string`. you can log the `$e->getResponse()` and write `throw $e` after that

Comment: Ok but what should I write here at `catch (BadResponseException $e)`

Comment: As a good practice - there should be a single error handler, for logging errors and returning some response... So - no. For example you could use an error handler to catch any errors, log them and return a json object with error information and http status code 4xx / 5xx. I have implemented this on my symfony3 project, using rest api bundle

Comment: Sounds good. So I should write only `catch (Exception $e)` and the log the message and then return json with error code?

Comment: It depends on your business logic. You can as you wrote, but you can also handle different errors in different way, for exampe having multiple `catch` blocks or use some kind of bundle that is working like that or using `instanceof` in a single `catch` block, but I prefer multiple `catch` blocks over this.